# Call many instances of a linked WPF User Library Control within a c# Windows Form

Tags: c#, charts, wpf-controls, 2d, graphic

I'm developping a software which collects a bunch of data that I'd like to display within 2d graphics.

I used [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17097/WPF-Chart-Control-With-Pan-Zoom-and-More) to perform it.
It works perfectly for a single call of that WPF embed control.

But the thing is that I need to call it many times (for each dataset) and I need to keep each instantiated object in memory, so that I can use the WPF Control functionnalities (Zoom, move, ...) within my C# windows form.

The problem is that I get an Exception while trying to access it more than 1 time at the same moment (because I'm calling a library). I get an error message telling me that the library is already used by another thread...

Is there some way to solve / avoid that issue ??
(I already tested many 2d graphic projects and this one seemed to be the more ease to use and suitable for me)

Comment: Why dont you add every instance created of the usercontrol in a list

Comment: Doesn't work... I moved back to the System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization option using this code snippet :: `http://snipplr.com/view/25227/`